# Is an email form to dynamic assigned recipients and senders in Rails possible?

Tags: ruby, forms, email, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm creating Rails app as a guide to restaurants whereby information is displayed regarding each restaurant, menus etc. It is a supporting website to an iOS app.

I would like to do allow the user to book or send an email to book a table on a restaurant. I'm storing both user and restaurant e-mails in my app.

I could easily do this in the iOS app using the Mail app but I'd like to offer the same functionality within my Rails version also. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

As @CarlZulauf commented, you are looking for [Rails e-mail interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html). It is hard to help you here because you didn't explain to us what did you tried and what is not working. If you have problems, you might want to create a new question, or edit this one, including the info, otherwise it is impossible for any one to help you more than just give you the doc link.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I've looked at the links but hopefully to make it clearer, I wondering if what I'm trying to achieve is even possible to begin with. Exactly what I wish to do is - on my Rails site the user can view restaurant profiles (this can be any amount). If logged in, I wish to the user to be able to book a table by email at that restaurant. Therefore, I wish the sender and recipient to be dynamically generated. Is this possible, or is some email configuration required for either party?

Comment: Sorry @fotanus what I'm asking is... The iOS app allows users to send an email to the restaurant profile they are viewing to provisionally make a reservation (straight forward in iOS as this is handled by the Mail app). Is this achievable in my Rails app? Basically I need a form which will send an email to the email address of the restaurant profile being viewed from the email of the logged in user? I can get these addresses but can the sender and the receiver of the email be dynamically assigned without any configuration? I hope this is clearer.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to create a method on your mailer as `book_resto(client_email, resto_email)` and on it use the mail call like this `mail(:to => resto_email, :from => client_email)`. Created that, on the action you have both emails, simply call `YourMailer.book_resto(var_with_cient_mail, var_with_resto_email)`.